# How to modify the values in a group based on the presance of some other value in the group using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

This is my data

```
structure(list(group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C", "D", "D", "D"), type = c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", 
"T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3"), value = c("MC", "C", NA, 
"C", "C", NA, "MA", "A", "A", NA, "MA", "MA")), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   group type  value
   <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 A     T1    MC   
 2 A     T2    C    
 3 A     T3    NA   
 4 B     T1    C    
 5 B     T2    C    
 6 B     T3    NA   
 7 C     T1    MA   
 8 C     T2    A    
 9 C     T3    A    
10 D     T1    NA   
11 D     T2    MA   
12 D     T3    MA
```

For each group there are 3 types. When there is a 'M' value in the group (MC or MA) then the rest of the values in the group should be changed to that value but the NA should remain as NA.

This is my expected output:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   group type  value
   <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 A     T1    MC   
 2 A     T2    MC    
 3 A     T3    NA   
 4 B     T1    C    
 5 B     T2    C    
 6 B     T3    NA   
 7 C     T1    MA   
 8 C     T2    MA    
 9 C     T3    MA    
10 D     T1    NA   
11 D     T2    MA   
12 D     T3    MA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df1 <- structure(list(group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D"), 
               type = c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3"), 
               value = c("MC", "C", NA, "C", "C", NA, "MA", "A", "A", NA, "MA", "MA")), 
          row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Solution using `dplyr` and an `ifelse` in mutate (for illustrative purpose I did not overwrite `value` but assign to a new variable...)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(newValue = ifelse(!is.na(value) & any(grepl("^M", value)), value[grepl("M", value)][1], value))
```

Returns:

```
   group type  value newValue
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   
 1 A     T1    MC    MC      
 2 A     T2    C     MC      
 3 A     T3    NA    NA      
 4 B     T1    C     C       
 5 B     T2    C     C       
 6 B     T3    NA    NA      
 7 C     T1    MA    MA      
 8 C     T2    A     MA      
 9 C     T3    A     MA      
10 D     T1    NA    NA      
11 D     T2    MA    MA      
12 D     T3    MA    MA
```

A comment: Just be aware that right now the behaviour is somewhat undefined if multiple different "M" values appear within a group. But I assume that this is prevented by the data structure/logic...

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` you can try this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(any(grepl("M", value)) & value %in% c("C", "A") ~ paste0("M", value),
                           TRUE ~ value)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Which results in:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   group type  value
   <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 A     T1    MC   
 2 A     T2    MC   
 3 A     T3    NA   
 4 B     T1    C    
 5 B     T2    C    
 6 B     T3    NA   
 7 C     T1    MA   
 8 C     T2    MA   
 9 C     T3    MA   
10 D     T1    NA   
11 D     T2    MA   
12 D     T3    MA
```